# HTC One (m7ul) not found by ADB + formatted filesystem = bricked?

Tags: usb, adb, unbricking, fastboot

So, I'm really hoping that I haven't bricked my phone and that someone can help me figure out how to fix this.

I can't remember exactly the steps I took to mess it up so spectacularly, but they included trying to flash to the M2 snapshot of CyanogenMod 11 from a ViperOne ROM, relocking the bootloader, attempting to restore to a stock RUU (and failing because I accidentally downloaded an unsigned version), reUNlocking the bootloader, and formatting via TWRP.

Fastboot appears to recognise that the phone is plugged in (it reads `FASTBOOT USB` on the bootloader screen), and Windows 8 sees the device in Device Manager. However, when I attempt to do anything with ADB it returns `error: device not found`, so I can't use rebootRUU or push files to the /sdcard/ directory, and I have no ROMs to flash.

The bootloader screen reads:

```
*** TAMPERED ***
*** RELOCKED ***
*** Security Warning ***
M7_UL PVT SHIP S-ON RH
HBOOT-1.54.0000
RADIO-4A.17.3250.14
OpenDSP-v31.120.274.0617
OS-2.24.841.1
eMMC-boot 2048MB
Jun 21 2013,23:03:15.0

FASTBOOT USB
```

It also appears that I am able to use FastBoot to lock and unlock the bootloader using the unlock bin file I created earlier today, yet `fastboot devices` returns nothing and `fastboot reboot` returns `< waiting for devices >`.

Is there anything I can do short of using a USB-OTG cable to sideload a custom ROM?

I would be inconceivably grateful for any help which gets me closer to getting my phone working again. Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT 1: So, after rebooting a couple of times, `*** Security Warning ***` is no longer there and `fastboot devices` now returns my serial number. However, `adb devices` still returns nothing. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Can you boot into your recovery? There should be a 'mount USB' option (or similar depending on the recovery)? Unlock the bootloader, mount the usb, copy the ROM over and flash...

Comment: As soon as you can, I recommend taking your second edit and using it to answer your question! Your experience matches my own - Windows (Even Windows 7) can be *really* finnicky with ADB and Fastboot. I've just defaulted to using Linux and OSX for all my Android-related stuff.

Comment: @dotVezz - thanks for the heads up - I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Woah! I'm not entirely sure what happened, but it suddenly started working again - I now have CM 11 up and running.

Here are some notes on what I was doing which will hopefully be helpful for someone else who has the same problems I did:

- First off, I was running Windows 8 in a Parallels VM. I don't know if either Windows 8 or the VM was the culprit, but either way, it was silly and probably didn't help things. Getting ADB and FastBoot up and running in OS X seemed to make a difference.
- Also, there is a chance that there were some problems with directory partitioning/formatting - it suddenly started working after I wiped the system a few times with TWRP **(Wipe > Format Data)** and rebooted. Obviously you'll lose everything, but better to lose a few files and get your phone back!

Other info that I found that wasn't relevant to me but might make a difference:

- Apparently USB 3 can cause issues - try different USB ports, particularly USB 2 over USB 3.
- Windows 8 may not play nice - try Windows 7 or XP (or Linux!)